# Google map universities location

Tags: google-maps

I need to get the location information of universities, I just managed to get information about school.
But I want to see just universities. How can I do that?

```
 {
        "featureType": "poi.school",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't offer universities in their [style references](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference).
But if you need access to location information, maybe it is useful for you to use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro). It definitely offers you the option to filter [places by type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) "university".

Comment: Yea, i was looking for shortcut, thanks for the answer.